# Django on APP Engine - error redirecting a URL path to an existing function in views.py (on urls.py)

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm getting an error when I try to redirect a URL path to an existing function inside of a views.py file.

I realize where the problem is, but I cannot figure out how to solve it.

I have the following structure of folders on my project:

```
my_app_gae
  app.yaml
  main.py
  settings.py
  urls.py
  my_app_django (<-- here is my django project)
    dashboard
      views.py
    models
      models.py
```

The problem comes here:

when I edit the urls.py file, when I try to redirect a specific URL path to an existing function inside of views.py (landing), I recieve the following error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8090/landing/
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    No module named my_app_django
```

The value of my Python Path is: V:\Python~1\my_app_gae (the place where the structure of folders I wrote before is).

The url.py value that I'm trying to execute is:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from my_app_django.dashboard.views import landing

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    (r'^landing/$', landing),
)
```

If I copy the views.py file directly on the my_app_gae directory it works. The problem comes when the views.py file is inside of other directories.

Thanks a lot.

Regards

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` files in all those subdirectories?

Comment: Not... actually I don't have that file in anything of them. How can I create it? or what I'm doing wrong to be in this situation? (without that file in anything of my directories?) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be recognized as a Python package, you need empty files named `__init__.py` in each subdirectory.